# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'call'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Using the jquery validate plugin, I want to show/hide error only when the element's blur event is called, dont want to show error message as you type. To fix this I tried

```
$('#form').validate({
    onfocusout: true,
    onkeyup: false
});
```

but as soon I click outside any element it throws error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'call'
```

Comment: Setting `onfocusout` to `true` is _'not a valid value'_ [as per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

its `onfocusout` not `onfoucusout`, change to:

```
$('#form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); },
    onkeyup: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
});
```

Comment: I just need to return true for onkeyup method then it works only onfocusout. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @coure2011, You cannot set the `onkeyup` or `onfocusout` options to `true`.  They are enabled by default.  Check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by Sudhir, you've misspelled the `onfocusout` option.

Additionally, the `onfocusout` and `onkeyup` options are already enabled **by default** in this plugin.

You only have two choices...

1) If you want to disable `onfocusout` or `onkeyup`, you would set them to `false`...

```
$('#form').validate({
    onfocusout: false, // disable validation on blur
    onkeyup: false     // disable validation on key-up
});
```

2) If you want to modify the default behavior of `onfocusout` or `onkeyup`, you would set them to your custom function...

```
$('#form').validate({
    onfocusout: function(element, event) {
        // your custom callback function for blur event
    },
    onkeyup: function(element, event) {
        // your custom callback function for key-up event
    }
});
```

Otherwise, if you simply want the default behavior of the `onfocusout` or `onkeyup` options, *leave them out* of the `.validate()` call entirely.  [As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/), setting these to `true` *"is not a valid value"* and will break the plugin.

```
$('#form').validate({
    // onfocusout: true, // <- remove this line, true value is not valid
    // onkeyup: true     // <- remove this line, true value is not valid
});
```

---

**Documentation:**

> **onfocusout**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur**. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was
>   already marked as invalid. Set to a Function to decide for yourself
>   when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid value**.

---

> **onkeyup**
>  Type: Boolean or Function()
>   **Validate elements on keyup**. As long as the field is not marked as invalid, nothing happens. Otherwise, all rules are checked on each key
>   up event. Set to false to disable. Set to a Function to decide for
>   yourself when to run validation.  **A boolean true is not a valid
>   value**.